# Keep Offset keeps doesn't work as planned

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, parent

I have been following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGvalWG8HBU

And I reached the part where he assigned 2 bones and kept it as offset. The problem that I am facing is that whenever I do Keep Offset, the Foot keeps disconnecting from the Leg and joins up with the Leg IK. Any Ideas for solution???

Answer (score -1):

You have to go to pose mode after "Keep Offset".